# Why am I getting a URL launcher error instead of being redirected to the website when I click on my Flutter application?

Tags: html, flutter, http, web-scraping

**I want to fetch data from Amazon's website, list the products, and then navigate to Amazon's site by tapping on the listed items in the application. However, I encountered the following error;**

E/flutter (15082): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: Could not launch /sspa/click?

E/flutter (15082): #0      _AmazonScrapingPageState._launchURL (package:web_scraping/main.dart:59:7)

**And that is my code below ;**

```
  void _parseProductData(String htmlString) {
    var document = dom.parse(htmlString);
    var productElements = document.querySelectorAll('.s-result-item');

    productElements.forEach((element) {
      var titleElement =
      element.querySelector('.a-size-base-plus.a-color-base.a-text-normal');
      var priceElement = element.querySelector('.a-price');
      var linkElement = element.querySelector('a.a-link-normal');

      if (titleElement != null && priceElement != null && linkElement != null) {
        var title = titleElement.text.trim();
        var price = priceElement.text.trim();
        var link = linkElement.attributes['href'];

        productTitles.add(title);
        productPrices.add(price);
        productLinks.add(link!);
      }
    });
  }

  Future<void> _launchURL(String url) async {
    if (await canLaunch(url)) {
      await launch(url);
    } else {
      throw 'Could not launch $url';
    }
  }

  @override
             child: ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: productTitles.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        _launchURL(productLinks[index]);
                      },
```

**The screen displays selected products along with their prices, but when I tap on the products, I can't navigate to the product links. Already tried flutter clean , and closing app then flutter run .**